# Application Plugin

Tags: delphi, plugins, shared-memory

I'm developing some plugins to my application using the JEDI Plugin tecnology, but I run into a lot of problems with memory sharing specially when it handles Database connection. The main application uses the FASTMM4 memory manager. Does any one knows a bit more easy framework to work with plugins?

Comment: Where is your database connection (main app or plugin)?  How is database-related information being passed between the main app and the plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVCL plugin manager works just fine, but if you want to share memory properly with your plugins, you need to add SimpleShareMem.pas to the uses clause of both your app and the plugins, at the top of the uses list in the project file.

Answer (score 1):

Do your plugins also use FASTMM4?  You need to make sure you are using the same memory manager in both the application and the plugin.